# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I got error like.
**Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

```
if ($_POST['submit'] ?? '' == "Log In") {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE (email, password) LIKE (:email, :password)";

    $stmt = $link -> prepare($query);
    $stmt -> bindValue(':email', $_POST['loginemail'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindValue(':password', md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']).$_POST['loginpassword']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $rows = $stmt -> fetchAll();

}
```

but There's no error in this statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT ko_name FROM dogBREEDS WHERE dogBREEDS.ko_name LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
```

How can I solve this? and What's the difference??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$query = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE (email, password) LIKE (:email, :password)";`

This sql is not a right sql in correct syntax. [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html)(or take a look of here [MySQL LIKE Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm)) can not be used like this, try this please;)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE email LIKE (:email) and password LIKE (:password)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed like this.

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM member WHERE email=:email AND password=:password";

$stmt = $link -> prepare($query);
$stmt -> bindParam(':email', $_POST['loginemail'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> bindValue(':password', md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']).$_POST['loginpassword']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> execute();
```